# Audio streaming using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to develop one app where i will be having **Play** and **Stop** buttons .Once i click on Play button it should stream the audio which is being played on a particular link

```
-(void)playMusic
{  
   mAudioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tuneindia.com"] error:nil];
   mAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
   mAudioPlayer.volume=mVolumeSlider.value;
   NSLog(@"THEVOLUME::::   %f",mVolumeSlider.value);
   [mAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
   [mAudioPlayer play];
}
```

Kindly help me to understand how this AVAudioPlayer gets attached to a link and stream the audio from there (as we have used www.tuneindia.com).

Answer (score 4):

AVAudioPlayer is not meant for streaming. Init with URL is only meant for local file urls. Use AVPlayer to stream.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

In case you are wondering why it doesn't play music as you have written it, then the reason is that www.tuneindia.com refers to a webpage and not the particular stream. The stream on that webpage is located somewhere else (check the HTML source, it is seemingly not allowed to post that link here on StackOverflow). However, it may well be that you still cannot play it, the first parameter looks like a session cookie.

If you want to test your code, upload an MP3 file to a server where you can store files and then reference the URL in the player initialization like this: http://www.yourserver.com/path/to/yourmusic.mp3.

Comment: whatever you told is fine. Actually if you open that website it will automatically plays some music and i want to play that music in my app.

Comment: and if i give the server url where the songs have been stored than will it work?

Comment: You have to create an URL that points to the actual stream, not just the server itself. AVAudioPlayer is not clever enough to figure out that you want to play a stream that is embedded into an HTML page. The reason this works in a normal browser is that the page also embeds an application that automatically plays the stream as soon as you open the page. The URL you have to point AVAudioPlayer to needs to be the same that the embedded application is pointed to. Referring to tuneindia.com, you can find that URL by looking at the HTML page's source.